# angular 8 - routerLink issue. when click on anchor tag which have routerLink property it does not do anything

Tags: angular

routerLink is not working in angular 8.
I have imported router module still getting the issue.

```
<div class="dashboard-container dashboard-container1 activedashboard text-left">
  <p>
    <a routerLink="/Dashboard">
      <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      Dashboard
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

And below is the dashboard configurations

```
 @NgModule({
  "declarations": ["AppComponent", "LoginComponent"],
  "imports": ["BrowserModule", "AppRoutingModule", "FormsModule", "ReactiveFormsModule", "RouterModule.forRoot(" [{
      "path": "",
      "component": "LoginComponent"
    }, {
      "path": "login",
      "component": "LoginComponent"
    }, {
      "path": "Dashboard",
      "component": "DashboardComponent"
    }]
    ")"
  ],
  "providers": [],
  "bootstrap": ["AppComponent"]
})
```

here is an image for the same with formatting `NgModule` Configuration :

[image]

Comment: You need to provide some code so people can help you easier.

Comment: Could you show where you are declaring the `/Dashboard` route

Comment: Please add your router configurations

Comment: declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
    ])
  ],